# Python dataframe name error: name is not defined

Tags: python, list, dataframe, web-scraping

I scraped the link and address of each property on page 1 of a real estate website into a list. I then convert this list of lists `listing_details` into pandas dataframe by appending info of each property as a row (20 rows in total). My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "https://www.realestate.co.nz/residential/sale/auckland?by=latest&oad=true&pm=1&scat=1%2C7%2C2%2C4%2C6%2C5%2C3%2C50%2C53"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
listings = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

listing_details = []

details = listings.findAll('div', attrs={"data-test":"tile"})
for detail in details:

    # get property links
    links = detail.findAll('a', href=True)
    for link in links:
        link="https://www.realestate.co.nz" + link['href']
    
    # get addresses
    addresses = detail.findAll('h3')
    for address in addresses:
        address=address.text.strip()

df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(listing_details, columns=['Link','Location']), ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

However, I got the following error: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`

I changed the last two lines into `print(listing_details)` to see if there's something wrong with the list but found that I got 20 empty lists.

But when I write `print(link)` and `print(address)` I can see that I did scrape the correct information as follows:

```
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016546/residential/sale/3436-westgate-drive-westgate
34-36 Westgate Drive, Westgate
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016545/residential/sale/3436-westgate-drive-westgate
34-36 Westgate Drive, Westgate
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016519/residential/sale/7-ckaitiaki-drive-clarks-beach
7C Kaitiaki Drive, Clarks Beach
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016178/residential/sale/6423427-beach-road-mairangi-bay
6/423-427 Beach Road, Mairangi Bay
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016177/residential/sale/4423427-beach-road-mairangi-bay
4/423-427 Beach Road, Mairangi Bay
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016176/residential/sale/2423427-beach-road-mairangi-bay
2/423-427 Beach Road, Mairangi Bay
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016163/residential/sale/303428-dominion-road-mount-eden
303/428 Dominion Road, Mount Eden
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016162/residential/sale/316428-dominion-road-mount-eden
316/428 Dominion Road, Mount Eden
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016127/residential/sale/50910-kingdon-street-newmarket
509/10 Kingdon Street, Newmarket
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016057/residential/sale/3-s99-customs-street-west-auckland-central
3S/99 Customs Street West, Auckland Central
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4016005/residential/sale/80270-daldy-street-wynyard-quarter
802/70 Daldy Street, Wynyard Quarter
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015970/residential/sale/20-crown-lynn-place-new-lynn
20 Crown Lynn Place, New Lynn
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015916/residential/sale/3-s15-nelson-street-auckland-central
3S/15 Nelson Street, Auckland Central
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015773/residential/sale/lot7280-fred-taylor-drive-westgate
Lot 72, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Westgate
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015774/residential/sale/lot4280-fred-taylor-drive-westgate
Lot 42, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Westgate
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015772/residential/sale/lot4580-fred-taylor-drive-massey
Lot 45, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Massey
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015771/residential/sale/lot6680-fred-taylor-drive-massey
Lot 66, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Massey
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015759/residential/sale/lot7280-fred-taylor-drive-massey
Lot 72, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Massey
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015757/residential/sale/lot4780-fred-taylor-drive-westgate
Lot 47, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Westgate
https://www.realestate.co.nz/4015758/residential/sale/lot4580-fred-taylor-drive-westgate
Lot 45, 80 Fred Taylor Drive, Westgate
```

Any ideas on where I did wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you are not appending anything to `listing_details`. Your `for` loop should look something like this:

```
for detail in details:

    # get property links
    links = detail.findAll('a', href=True)
    for link in links:
        link="https://www.realestate.co.nz" + link['href']
    
    # get addresses
    addresses = detail.findAll('h3')
    for address in addresses:
        address=address.text.strip()

    listing_details.append(address, link) # You can decide the order or address and link.
```

Comment: Thank you! I found that ```listing_details.append([link, address])``` would be the correct way tho. But I still got the NameError.

Comment: That's cuz you're defining `df` in the same line and using it too, remove `df.append` from the code and it would work just fine

Comment: Never mind I've sorted it out by removing ```append()``` from ```df``` in the original code. Thanks anyway